# Generate Cloud Endpoints file in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

In Eclipse there's an easy way to generate Endpoints file from a Java class(right click on class -> google -> generate endpoints file), but I cannot find this feature in **IntelliJ**.
How should I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin that supports Cloud Endpoints generation is currently available only in Android Studio, but not in IntelliJ IDEA. If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, you need to use the [command line `endpoints` tool](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/endpoints_tool) to generate the endpoints file.