# How to generate google cloud endpoint API in intellj?

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-endpoints

It's very easy to generate `Google cloud Endpoint API` in eclipse but How to create them in `Intellij`?

So, I added it manually and also I can see endpoints in `target/appengine-endpoints/WEB-INF/endpoint` but after successfully deploying I cannot see in appengine datastore section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate Cloud Endpoints file in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843308/generate-cloud-endpoints-file-in-intellij-idea)